# Adding click events to Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

Here is my Jquery data tables to get the values from ajax and placing it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt"
    });
});
```

Here is the constructed table.

I want to write click function to it. How can i do it ?

```
<table id="example" class="table dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 299px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">TMB030</td>
            <td>Sample Collected</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1">TMB033</td>
            <td>Sample Collected</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to write click event to the role="row" and get the value `TMB030` on it.

How can i do that ?

I tried like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "myOrders/" + Cookies.get('userSession')
    });
    $("div[role='row']").click(function() {
        alert('clicked')
    });
});
```

But it is not triggered how can i do that ? Help pls

Comment: Should it not be `tr[role='row']`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$( document ).on("click", "tr[role='row']", function(){
    alert($(this).children('td:first-child').text())
});
```

Brief Explanation:

1. On initial page load(that is when `document.ready` callback function is executed), the Datatable elements (rows and columns etc) are not yet present in the DOM Tree. They are created at runtime in response to data changes. Therefor the callback function provided in `document.click` method will not get bind to any element (i.e. `div[role='row']`).
2. To overcome it, `.on` method is available. It binds the callback function to click event of elements already in the DOM and also to elements that are created dynamically.

Comment: add more description to your answer

Comment: description has been added.

Answer (score 8):

If you are loading your Table by ajax, maybe would be better use the function "initComplete" of dataTable, then you could bind events to any element in the table when you are totally sure of all rows are present.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": "myOrders/" + Cookies.get('userSession'),
    "initComplete": function () {
            $( document ).on("click", "tr[role='row']", function(){
                 alert($(this).children('td:first-child').text())
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your click to this:

```
 $( "tr[role='row']" ).on("click",function(){
     alert($(this).find("td:first-child").text());
});
```

Sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("tr[role='row']").on("click",function() {
    alert($(this).find("td:first-child").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 299px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">TMB030</td>
      <td>Sample Collected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">TMB033</td>
      <td>Sample Collected</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.click` event will not bind on dynamic elements, In your case rows will be loaded after `ajax` call.

So change code to below

```
$("tr[role='row']" ).on('click', function(){
  alert('clicked')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$( document ).on("click", "#example tr[role='row']", function(){
       alert($(this).children('td:first-child').text())
});
```